# Sobolev embedding on sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

Let $S$ be a two-dimensional sphere, $\Delta$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $S$ and $L^p(S)$, $p\geq 1$, be the usual $L^p$ space of real-valued functions on $S$. We also set $\|f\|_{H^\alpha(S)}:=\|(1-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}f\|_{L^2(S)}$,
$\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $p\in[2,\infty)$ and $\alpha=1-2/p$.
Is it true that there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $f\in H^\alpha(S)$ it holds

$$ \|f\|_{L^p(S)} \leq C \|f\|_{H^\alpha(S)}? $$

Comment: It might be overkill, but surely spherical harmonic expansions (with their sup-norm and L^2 norm comparisons, as in Stein-Weiss, e.g.) would resolve such issues?

Comment: Is $S$ the round sphere, or the Riemannian metric is arbitrary?

Comment: S is the "round" sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the metric induced from $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: This can be proved using the heat semigroup generated by the Laplace Beltrami. I guess I can fill the details but I cannot do right now.... Probably in 2-3 days, if you still need it.

Answer (score 1):

Today I could check, finally. The proof I had in mind works in any dimension with $\alpha >(N-1)(1/2-1/p)$ (in your case $N=3$) which is not optimal. The optimal result with equality is proved in Theorem II.2.7, Varopoulos, Saloff-Coste, Coulhon, Analysis and Geometry on groups.